# Manipulating infinitely small $dx$

Tags: derivatives, infinitesimals

- From basic infinitesimal calculus, we know that the $$\frac{dy}{dx}=1$$ implies $$dy=dx.$$ However, what is the exact argument behind this result?
- Now, consider $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=1.$$ Why can't we say that $$d^2y=dx^2?$$

Comment: You can't say that $\frac{dy}{dx} = 1$ implies that $dy = dx$, because the second equation is meaningless. $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a function which is written like a fraction, it is not a fraction, $dy$ and $dx$ have no meaning in themselves.

Comment: @DuncanRamage Fair comment but this is how separable ODEs are solved isn't it? $dy/dx+y=0$ implies $dy/y=-dx$ and so on...

Comment: @pluton This is usually ill-defined in courses on ODEs. It does work in you specific example, because you **can** make this specific argument more formal. But keep in mind that such treatment fails in general. For example, from the chain rule of a function of three variables you could get $$\frac{{\rm d}f}{{\rm d}t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{{\rm d} x}{{\rm d} t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{{\rm d} y}{{\rm d} t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{{\rm d} z}{{\rm d} t}=3\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$$ which is of course wrong.

Comment: @DuncanRamage This way of thinking is also used when you calculate integrals with a change of variables: $\int f(x)dx$ with $x=h(t)$ becomes $\int g(t) dt$ where $dx=h'(t)dt$...

Comment: @pluton Just because it's a useful mnemonic doesn't mean that it's meaningful as a mathematical statement.

Comment: @DuncanRamage Yes, you are correct, the proof (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) does not use this "trick".

Comment: @DuncanRamage, what you are claiming in effect is that infinitesimals are "meaningless". This is an interesting hypothesis.  Consider however the fact that the tag [tag:infinitesimals] has no fewer than 232 questions under it. Apparently some editors disagree with your assessment.  Therefore your claim requires additional argument.

Comment: @MikhailKatz My *real* argument is that people who are arguing that $\frac{dy}{dx} = 1$ implies $dy = dx$ because that's how it's done for ODE's need to stop and reexamine what they've learned. My *real* argument is pedagogical in nature, and not mathematical, but pretending the argument is mathematical produces better results.

Comment: @pluton If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: @DuncanRamage, what you seem to be saying is that saying a falsehood "produces better results" and that's why you did it.  This is rarely, if ever, the case.

Comment: @MikhailKatz I think this is a philosophical point on which we won't agree. It is my experience as a teacher though, that simplifying and ignoring some concepts, e.g., the rigorous bedrock of calculus 1, makes better students.

Comment: @DuncanRamage, I am fine to disagree on a philosophical point.  What I think is unhelpful is misrepresenting the situation by making it appear that you are presenting solid fact, rather than what it really is, namely, a personal philosophical position.  I don't really follow your point about "rigorous bedrock" since both the epsilon-delta and the infinitesimal approaches are rigorous.  Furthermore, both rely on material that is *not* covered in a freshman calculus course, such as completeness of the reals, which is material that properly belongs in a  real *analysis* course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't say that:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=1\implies d^2y=dx^2$$

because $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is not a ratio, it's just a symbol for second derivative.

What you can say is that:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=1\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=x+a \implies y=\frac12 x^2+ax+b $$

For:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1$$ it's true that it implies that $y=x+a$ and thus that finite or infinitesimal increments $dy$ are equal $dx$. However also in this case $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not a ratio but just a symbol for the first derivative.

Comment: Your answer is inappropriate for the tag [tag:infinitesimals]. Indeed $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a ratio.

Comment: I think it’s a matter of notation. Assuming dy/dx as a ratio can lead at great misunderstandings as for the case we are discussing about. Of course it’s possible to do it but in a elementary approach is better to avoid this notation.

Comment: Gimusi, your claim that "in an elementary approach is better to avoid this notation" is an interesting hypothesis.  However, it should be formulated as a hypothesis rather than a blanket claim as you would have it.  Furthermore there is plenty of classroom evidence that tends to refute your hypothesis; see for example [this 2017 publication in Journal of Humanistic Mathematics](http://dx.doi.org/10.5642/jhummath.201701.07).

Comment: I claim that it should be avoid since, if not properly defined, it can lead easily to misunderstanding. Indeed the correct formulation requires "non-standard analysis".

Comment: Gimusi, your contention that "in an elementary approach it is better to avoid this notation" is precisely what I am contesting based on my teaching experience. I suspect that your claim is not based on teaching experience. You can see the article I cited as well as [Keisler's textbook *Elementary Calculus*](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html).

Answer (score 3):

Since this *question* was posted under the tag [infinitesimals](/questions/tagged/infinitesimals) it is reasonable to assume that the OP expects an answer in terms of a theory of infinitesimals.  There are several such theories that meet modern standards of rigor.  The most common such system is of course Abraham Robinson's framework for analysis with infinitesimals, relying on a hyperreal number system which is an ordered field properly extending the field of real numbers.

In such a framework, the derivative of $y=f(x)$ is defined as the slope $m=f'(x)=\mathbf{st}\left(\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\right)$ where $\Delta x$ is an infinitesimal increment of the independent variable $x$ and $\Delta y$ is the corresponding increment of the dependent variable $y$, i.e., $\Delta y=f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)$.  Note that, contrary to the infinitesimal-free (epsilon-delta) approach, the ratio $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ already contains the full information about the slope $m$, via the application of the standard part function $\mathbf{st}$.

Then the independent variable $dx$ is defined simply by $dx=\Delta x$ whereas the *dependent* variable $dy$ is defined by $dy=f'(x)dx$.  In the case $m=1$ one naturally obtains $dy=dx$, as the OP suggested.

Similarly, for second derivatives one defines the dependent variable $d^2y$ by setting $d^2y=f''(x)dx^2$ so one naturally has $d^2y= f''(x)dx^2$ and so whenever the second derivative equals $1$ one obtains $$d^2y=dx^2,$$ as the OP suggested.

The notation closely parallels the second differences $\Delta^2 y= f(x)-2f(x+\Delta x)+f(x+2\Delta x)$ and behaves similarly.

For more information see Keisler's textbook for calculus with infinitesimals entitled [Elementary Calculus](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html).

Note. For a related post see [this discussion of Leibnizian formalism](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/888250/72694).

Answer (score 2):

You can't play with "infinitesimal" objects like that. The expression

$$\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}$$

is not a fraction, but rather a **notation** of the following limit

$$\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{y\left(x+h\right)-y\left(x\right)}{h}$$

Comment: But the limit itself can be defined as the standard part of the ratio of infinitesimals $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$.  Your answer is inappropriate for the tag [tag:infinitesimals].

Comment: @MikhailKatz That's right, but the word infinitesimal is used so widely in early calculus classes that I am not sure the OP really meant to deal with hyperreal calculus. Nevertheless, it's good to have both answers.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect in the sense that it is indeed possible "to play with infinitesimal objects like that". If you want to give a long-winded paraphrase without infinitesimals that's fine but don't mislead the OP as to the true state of affairs.

Answer (score 2):

The basic, intuitive argument given in most lower division calculus classes is that we can treat the differentials like variables, and perform the kinds of manipulations you suggest.  This was the fundamental intuition (I think) that guided Leibniz's thinking, and lead to the $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ notation.  However, when analysis was axiomatized and put on a more solid foundation in the 19th and 20th centuries, the field was put in terms of limits, rather than infinitesimals.  Hence the Leibnizian intuition and notation doesn't quite match the modern way of thinking, causing the kind of disconnect that you are seeing.

On the other hand, there is an exact argument, via a field of analysis called *non-standard analysis*, formalized Abraham Robinson in the 1960s (his book is cited below).  The difficulty is that you cannot treat $\mathrm{d}x$ as an infinitesimal *real* number—the real numbers are inadequate to the task.  Instead, you have to adjoin or append objects called *infinitesimals* to the reals, obtaining the hyperreal numbers.

A discussion of non-standard analysis is, I believe, far beyond the scope of this website in general, and your question in particular, thus I would invite you glance at the book cited below.

*Robinson, Abraham*, Non-standard analysis, Princeton, NJ: Princeton Univ. Press. xix, 293 p. (1996). [ZBL0843.26012](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0843.26012).

Comment: Robinson's book may be beyond the level of this OP but Keisler's book is eminently appropriate; see my *answer*.